# onclick event not loading data in correct sequence

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onclick, preventdefault

I am making a simple website which consists of products (Laptop, CCTV). It has a single page. When I click on(Laptop  tag, it should display Laptop items stored in JSON - and the same case For CCTV products.

**Problem.**

1. The first time I click on a link it does not show anything, when I click 2nd, 3rd times on link then it shows products. But `preventdefault` is not working.
2. Where should i apply preventDefault() event and how?

**Html code for 2 links**

```
<a 
    href="displayproducts.html" onloadeddata="fetchproducts('CCTV')";>        
    CCTV CAMERAS</a>
<a
    href="displayproducts.html"
    onloadeddata="fetchproducts('Laptop')">
    Laptop and COMPUTERS</a>
```

**JavaScript Code** which handles that event and using **AJAX AND JSON** should return data (returning correctly).

```
function fetchproducts(product, event) {
  console.log(product);
  //your read json code

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("get", "/jsondata/Products.json");

  xhr.onload = function (event) {
    console.log();
    event.preventDefault();
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    try {
      if (product === "CCTV") {
        fillProducts(obj.CCTV);
      } else if (product === "Laptop") {
        fillProducts(obj.Laptop);
      } else if (product == "Biometric") {
        fillProducts(obj.Biometric);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("some_error_occur");
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: preventDefault needs to be outside the onload. By the time onload has fired, the event has already been complete.

Comment: kindly more elaborate

Comment: elaboration: put `event.preventDefault();` directly after `function fetchproducts(product, event) {`.

Comment: Keep the `event.preventDefault` after or before the `console.log(product)`. And remove it from inside `onload`. And you should pass `event` object from HTML to Javascript like `onloadeddata="fetchproducts('Laptop', event)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetchproducts(product, event) {
  console.log(product);
   

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("get", "/jsondata/Products.json", true);

  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log();
    try {
      var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
      if (product === "CCTV") {
        fillProducts(obj.CCTV);
      } else if (product === "Laptop") {
        fillProducts(obj.Laptop);
      } else if (product == "Biometric") {
        fillProducts(obj.Biometric);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("some_error_occur: " + error);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
  event.preventDefault();
}
```